# How to fix import error with modules on python docker

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, docker-compose, importerror

i'm creating an app and wanted to dockerize it. But after the build, when i do `sudo docker-compose up` i get the error `module cogs not found` at the line `from cogs import FILES` in my main file (josix.py).
I already checked several topics on StackOverflow about import errors with docker but none of them got me the right answer so i try with this one.

---

The code looks like this :

/app

- josix.py
- cogs/
- - **init.py** (containing `FILES` variable)
- - *others py files*

(init.py and other py files are inside cogs directory)

---

Dockerfile :

```
FROM python:3

WORKDIR /app

COPY Josix/* ./

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:/app/"

CMD [ "python3", "josix.py" ]
```

I tried to change the pythonpath, add several ones, change the import

Comment: Have you rebuilt your container after altering requirements?

Comment: Yes, i run `sudo docker-compose build` each time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `*` from your copy command to copy sub-directories as well as files (and you don't need to add to `PYTHONPATH` `/app` is already in it).

```
FROM python:3
WORKDIR /app
COPY Josix/ ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
CMD [ "python3", "josix.py" ]
```